# What are the best settings for the public folder in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, zend-framework2

I run my ZF2 projects on a linux server (CentOS).

I always have the same problem each time I setup a new project. What permissions to give my ZF2 public folder?

Each server setup is slightly different and sometimes permissions I used on one server are different for another.

For my projects, I use a cache system which copies files to the public folder, so naturally I need to give the system write permission to create the various folders.

What I am currently doing is to: chmod 757 public

I am not 100% sure if this is the best setting for a ZF2 public directory, what are the recommendations?

Comment: As you already mentioned, this depends on your setup. Granting rwx permissions to everyone is proably the worst way to go though. Your webserver only needs read permissions on this directory while php needs write permissions. How this can best be achieved depends on what user the webserver and php run under and if you can change any of the configuration. Maybe you could elaborate on this?

Comment: I am not very good with Linux and permissions and am not clued up on the conventions, I understand this notation: 777, 765 etc. What is the best way to test this... would there be an order? Essentially all I need is the ability to write new folders to the public directory, what permission would this be?

Comment: Well this depends on who needs these permissions - the directory owner, group members, ...? You certainly can allow everyone to write into this directory. But for example on shared hosting environments this may mean other clients using the same server might write in there as well (have seen this). I'd go with granting only the owner write permissions and change the owner of the public directory to the web server (often www-data). I recommend to read an introduction how linux users/groups & permission concepts on files to get an unterstanding on who will be able to write given which permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some research into this and a few questions on IRC it would appear that the best settings for the public folder are: 755

Now you may find when using something like AssetManager, PHP is unable to write to the public directory. To resolve this you need to find out what user PHP is using.

To do this I did the following:

```
1. Ran this command in my code: print shell_exec( 'whoami' );
```

This returned the user as "nobody"

Next I SSH'd into my server and navigated to the pre-public folder and ran the following command to find out who the public folder was set to:

```
2. Ran this command: ls -lah
```

This returned the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 router router 4.0K Apr 22 21:29 public/

3. Changed owner of public: chown nobody:nobody public
```

And finally I set the permissions of the public folder:

```
4. chmod 755 public
```

And now my public folder is set to the maximum permissible settings...